# How can i make price range filter in flutter and firebase firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make a filter search like that :
price: min to max price range
It is like minimum and maximum price between

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is:

```dart
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await productReference
    .where('price', isLessThanOrEqualTo: maxPrice)
    .where('price', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: minPrice)
    .get();
```

Comment: Hi, is this working GroupCollection ? , because I am using  indexes and I don't know 
what will happen about two same index

Comment: You don't need indexes for this request so it should always work